# laravel jwtAuth validate credentials

Tags: mysql, rest, laravel, jwt

I'm developing API in laravel and trying to implement token base auth with jwtAuth but what I cannot understand is that how to use mysql table 'customers' for authentication and generate token.
I have gone through multiple tutorials but none of them explain mysql table for authentication .

**Does mysql really required for jwtAuth ?

How to manage jwtAuth::attempt() function for mysql ?

What is default table for jwtAuth() ?**

Some of the tutorial that I have followed are : [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps) [and this](https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)

Comment: When using JWT authentication there is no extra table - you're using the usual users table (or whatever table you've defined for authentication). The tokens themselves are handled as session data, by default this is file based sessions and everything is stored in the `storage/framework/sessions` folder.

Comment: then how it will authenticate user credentials which are stored in mysql database ?

Comment: Using the authentication model you've defined in `config/auth.php` which by default will be the User model. This would authenticate against the users table.

Comment: JWTauth::attempt() will try to authenticate against my model that is defined in config/auth.php using mysql  and on success it will generate token! 
am i getting it right ?

Comment: Yes exactly right.

Comment: ok , let me try :)

Comment: add your comment in Answer Section , its working perfect !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT authentication is an extension of the base Authentication, and uses the same configuration and methods as defined in your `config/auth.php` file.

User data will be stored in the defined users table - if using the standard Authentication scaffolding this is just `users`.

The JWT sessions themselves will be stored based on your session configuration. By default this uses file based session,  stored within the 
folder `storage/framework/sessions`